# Position of GTS.CONTROL in Temenos OFS message header

Tags: temenos

Where in the Temenos OFS message header one can pass in the GTS.CONTROL parameter? I know that it is defined in the VERSION (application screen) in the field "GTS.CONTROL", but can it be overridden in the OFS message?

A sample message:

```
FUNFS.TRANSFER,BACKOFFICE/I/PROCESS,INPUTT/123456/GB0010001,,DEBIT.AMOUNT=100,....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GTS.CONTROL is the first slash-separated parameter after the PROCESS (Process type):

```
APPLICATION,VERSION/FUNCTION/PROCESS_TYPE/GTS_CONTROL/NO_OF_AUTHORISERS/,SIGN_ON_NAME/PASSWORD/COMPANY_CODE/,TRANSACTION_ID/MESSAGE_ID,MESSAGE_DATA
```

Here:

- APPLICATION - is T24 application name, e.g. FUNDS.TRANSFER
- VERSION - is the T24 screen name, e.g. BACKOFFICE
- FUNCTION - is the application function, typically I (for Input) or A (for Authorise)
- PROCESS_TYPE - can be either PROCESS (to validate and commit) or VALIDATE (to only validate the message)
- GTS_CONTROL - can be one of:

  - NULL - Reject errors / Approve overrides
  - 1 - Errors on HLD / Approve Overrides
  - 2 - Errors Rejected / Overrides in HLD
  - 3 - Errors in HLD / Overrides HLD
  - 4 - Hold Only
- NO_OF_AUTHORISERS - number of authorised required
- SING_ON_NAME - user name if authentication is required
- PASSWORD - password if authentication is required
- COMPANY_CODE - company/branch code where transaction must be done
- TRANSACTION_ID - record id, can be left blank to generate new id
- MESSAGE_ID - a unique message id that will be reported back in the answer and can be optionally saved in the log table (OFS.REQUEST.DETAIL)
- MESSAGE_DATA - comma separated "field = value" pairs

Example:

```
FUNFS.TRANSFER,BACKOFFICE/I/PROCESS/3/0,INPUTT/123456/GB0010001,,DEBIT.AMOUNT=100,....
```